# Not supported calendar message with PHP

Tags: php, email, outlook, calendar, icalendar

First off, I want to say I'm a very beginner in computing.

I am attempting to write some code which automatically sends an mail containing a new event in ics format.
I found a number of code samples on Internet to start with.

Here is my code

```
$desc= 'Rendez-vous dans le cadre de la résolution du ticket'.$ticket_id;
$headers = 'Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;\r\n';
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=\"utf-8\""; #EDIT: TYPO
$message = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
                            VERSION:2.0
                            PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
                            METHOD:REQUEST
                            BEGIN:VEVENT
                            UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "example.com
                            DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
                            DTSTART:".$startdate."T".$startTime."00Z
                            DTEND:".$enddate."T".$endTime."00Z
                            TRANSP:OPAQUE
                            SEQUENCE:0
                            SUMMARY:".$subject."
                            ORGANIZER;CN=".$organizer.":mailto:".$organizer_email."
                            LOCATION:".$location.', '.$site."
                            DESCRIPTION:".$desc."
                            PRIORITY:5
                            X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
                            CLASS:PUBLIC
                            ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:".$participant_email_1."                     
                            END:VEVENT
                            END:VCALENDAR";
$headers .= $message;
mail($participant_email_1, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Each variable has been verified and works fine. As I have seen on some discussions, the organizer mail is the same than the sender of the mail.

But when I receive the mail, outlook says it can "not supported calendar message.ics". Here is the content of the message.ics:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
                            VERSION:2.0
                            PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
                            METHOD:REQUEST
                            BEGIN:VEVENT
                            UID:91090dc834f3536fc3f37af82c1abe3aexample.com
                            DTSTAMP:20160920T142802Z
                             DTSTART:20160923T100000Z
                            DTEND:20160923T12000Z
                            TRANSP:OPAQUE
                            SEQUENCE:0
                            SUMMARY:test
                            ORGANIZER;CN=Marguerite Duras:mailto:example.example@example.example.com
                            LOCATION:Bordeaux, test
                            DESCRIPTION:Rendez-vous dans le cadre de la résolution du ticket17
                            PRIORITY:5
                            X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
                            CLASS:PUBLIC
                            ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:example.example@example.example.com                      
                            END:VEVENT
                            END:VCALENDAR
```

I have changed the mail addresses because it's my professional address...
Do anyone have any idea of what is going wrong here?
Sorry for the approximative english, I'm french so bad in foreign languages...

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Pleas provide the full  MIME message, as received on Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each iCalendar line must NOT begin with whitespace.  Remove all whitespace at the beginning of each line, like so:

```
$message = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
...
END:VCALENDAR";
```